# Firebase Cloud Messaging Android receive silent push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to migrate to Firebase cloud messaging from GCM and I noticed that when the application is not running the notifications are coming in the notifications tray. With GCM this was not the case, it was up to the developer to show a notification or not. I want to have similar behavior with FCM where when the app is running I want to silently handle the push message instead of having user to click on the notification and start the app. How can I achieve that.

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 12):

Firebase Cloud Messages has two types of messages:

1. **Notification Message**: this type of message has the same behavior as the GCM messages

> FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notification messages have a predefined set of user-visible keys

2. **Data Message**: this type has the behavior you described above.

> Client app is responsible for processing data messages.
>   Data messages have only custom key-value pairs.

**To send data messages you need to use the HTTP API [for Data Message].** <sub>(quoted from [Arthur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134894/firebase-cloud-messaging-android-receive-silent-push-notifications#comment63726899_38135781))</sub>

Full documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: To be clear: GMC also has notification messages that behave in a similar way. So FCM and GCM are very similar, the thing to note though is that messages sent from the console are always notification messages. To send data messages you need to use the HTTP API.

Comment: Thanks Arthur Thompson, I was facing the issue because I was using Firebase console to send the messages and hence they were always notifications. When I used HTTP API I was able to get the silent notifications

Comment: Thanks Petr! fixed

Comment: Can  I send only data message from FCM console?

Comment: Sagar: no it's not possible

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini It is possible with the new API too