# Is it possible to receive Firebase Silent Push Notification?

Tags: firebase, notifications

I have been developing Firebase Push Notification Integrated iOS application.
I already integrated some codes, and some settings.
So I can receive Firebase Silent Push Notification when app is in foreground.
But I have a issue when app is closed.
I close app. And I send Push Notification to closed app on other iPhone.
Closed app would not receive Push Notification. But if I open closed app later, I want to know that there are a few missing Push Notifications while app has been closed.
Is it possible to  know it ? 
And Could I handle missing Push Notifications?

Comment: Have you checked out this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134894/firebase-cloud-messaging-android-receive-silent-push-notifications. Maybe helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. In fact, I send data message via web server. and I can receive data messages when app is opened. So I think that send messaging feature would be fine.